# create dynamic row in jsp using for loop

Tags: java, jsp

i want to create a table with dynamic no of rows by this way

```
<table width="89%" style="margin-left:30px;">                   <%
    for (int arrayCounter = 0; arrayCounter < documentList.size(); arrayCounter++) {

    %>
    <% 
    int test = arrayCounter;
    if((arrayCounter%2)==0)){                       
    %>
    <tr>
    <%
    } %>
     <td style="width:2%">

    </td>
     <td style="width:20%;align:left;">
     </td>

      <td style="width:30%;align:left;">

    </td>
    <% 
     if((arrayCounter%2)==0){
      %>
   </tr>
    <%   } %>

     <%
    }
     %>
     </table>
```

in my jsp  this way it will create 4 rows but according coding function it would create 2 row only if `documentlist.size()=4`;
help me !

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it will create only 2 tow when size is 4,
when size is 6 it will create 3 row. remove it statement from loop if you want to 
create rows equal to number if size

Answer (score 0):

remove if statements from loop and create rows normally.

change your loop with this
for (int arrayCounter = 0; arrayCounter < (documentList.size()/2); arrayCounter++)

and for last row you can have if statement which will compare
if (documentList.size()/2)-1 == arrayCounter).. then
you will get what you are looking for

else

for (int arrayCounter = 0; arrayCounter < documentList.size(); arrayCounter++) {

```
if (documentList.size()/2)-1 == arrayCounter){  create 1 row}else{
create 1st row and then arraycounter ++
create 2nd row and then arraycounter ++
```

}
}

Comment: do you thing it will solve our problem bcoz your loop run by size/2 times but we need to iterate all data ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use scriptlets in jsp, Jsp is is view layer, use as a view. there is servlet/java-beans to put your all java code.

There is jstl taglib, which has many inbuild functions, use it. you can get it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2)

In your case to loop over a list do like this:

- Add jstl library to your classpath
- First import jstl taglib in top of your jsp.
- Then you have jstl tags to use in your jsp.

To import jstl in jsp do like:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

for looping a `List` in jstl, there is `c:forEach` tag, you can use it like:

```
<c:forEach items="${documentList}" var="doc">
   //here you can access one element by doc like: ${doc}
</c:forEach>
```

If you want to generate table rows, for each documentList element, then do like:

```
<table width="89%" style="margin-left:30px;">
<c:forEach items="${documentList}" var="doc" varStatus="loop">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:2%">
      //here if you want loop index you can get like: ${loop.index}
    </td>
    <td style="width:20%;align:left;">
     //if you want to display some property of doc then do like: ${doc.someProperty}, 
      jstl will call getter method of someProperty to get the value.

    </td>
    <td style="width:30%;align:left;">

    </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1) for how to avoid java code in jsp.